# Calculate total over repeated cart item totals with angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've a simplified shopping cart like the following with a controller for each cart item:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="cart">
  <div ng-controller="cartCtrl">
    <table>
      <tr><th>qty</th><th>prize</th><th>total</th></tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in cartItems" ng-controller="cartItemCtrl">
        <td>
          <input ng-model="item.qty"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input ng-model="item.prize" />
        </td>
        <td>
          {{total}}
        </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
     total: {{cartTotal}}
   </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script>
(function(){

var cart = angular.module('cart', []);

cart.controller('cartCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.cartItems = [{},{},{},{}];
}]);

cart.controller('cartItemCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

  $scope.$watchCollection('item', function(){
    $scope.total = $scope.item.qty * $scope.item.prize;
  });
}]);

}());
  </script>
</html>
```

I couldn't make it work in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XY3n8/1/

Now I want to to calculate the cart total but I do not want to recalculate the item totals. Instead I want to reuse the already calculated item totals. How? (In my use case the item total calculation is a bit more complex.)

Answer (score 8):

You need to do a "deep" watch on the collection and object to get sub-totals and totals.  `$watchCollection` is better for knowing when things get added/removed.  `$watch` will look for changes in the existing object(s).

For encapsulating the item's total, there are several ways to do this, but I'd probably create an `Item` model (probably a better name) and inject it via a `factory`.  It removes the need for one of the controllers in this example, but requires you to create a module (which is best practice anyway)

How about this?

```
var ShoppingCart = angular.module('shoppingCart', []);

ShoppingCart.factory('Item', function() {
  function Item() {
    this.total = function() {
      return (this.qty * this.prize) || 0;
    }
  }

  return Item;
});

ShoppingCart.controller('cartCtrl', function($scope, Item) {
  $scope.cartItems = [new Item(), new Item(), new Item(), new Item()];

  $scope.$watch('cartItems', function() {
    var cartTotal = 0;

    $scope.cartItems.forEach(function(item) {
      cartTotal += item.total();
    });

    $scope.cartTotal = cartTotal;
  }, true);
});
```

And the HTML updates slightly.  You reference the module name in the `ng-app`, get rid of the sub-controller, and reference `item.total()` directly in the view.

```
<div ng-app="shoppingCart" ng:controller="cartCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr><th>qty</th><th>prize</th><th>total</th></tr>
    <tr ng:repeat="item in cartItems">
      <td>
        <input ng:model="item.qty"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input ng:model="item.prize" />
      </td>
      <td>
        {{item.total()}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  total: {{cartTotal}}
</div>
```

Here is a [working codepen](http://codepen.io/BrianGenisio/pen/xdBca).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. But I might not have made my question clear enough: I search a solution which does contain the qty * prize calculation only _once_. As I said my real calculation is more complex and I don't want to do write the calculation function multiple times.

Comment: Gotcha.  I didn't catch that.  There are several approaches, but I favor the approach of creating an model "class" with a total function, and injecting it via an Angular `factory`.  I've updated my example to show it doing that.

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach using the ng-init directive to extend the model and do the calculations.

http://www.ozkary.com/2015/06/angularjs-calculate-totals-using.html